# Getting Error while uploading image file to S3 via the AWS java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading image file to S3 via the AWS java SDK, 
Here is my code:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(basicAWSCredentials)

PutObjectRequest putObj = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folderPath, getFile(fileName,fileContentToUpload));

putObj.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
s3.putObject(putObj);
```

on windows system its working fine, but on linux its giving following error:

Error Message: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: Chrysanthemum.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: Please check the folder path, as in windows and linux the slashes (\ and /) will be used different. As you said its no such file or directory it might not able to locate the image file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
yes I am using (/) for linux

Comment: What SDK version are you using?

Comment: make sure the file is there before trying to upload

Comment: @kailashgaur is it still an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

linux is case sensitive. windows is not.

try to an "ls" and note the case.

use the same case in your program.